# Enable text copy from canvas in tcl

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I want to enable copying of the text placed on canvas. Is it possible to do so?
I have placed text using:

```
.c.canvasName create text 100 90 $var -font {Courier -12} ...
```

where var contains a tcl tk matrix.

Comment: The main thing you need to do is to set up the bindings. A place to start looking for how to do it is `ctext.tcl` “Text items in canvases” in the standard Tk widget demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Donal wrote, `ctext.tcl` gives many helpful hints on how to manage text items in canvases.

Note that it doesn't demonstrate copying text to the clipboard. Use the following code for a rudimentary clipboard copy function:

```
$c bind text <<Copy>> "textCopy $c"

...

proc textCopy {w} {
    clipboard clear
    clipboard append [selection get]
    selection clear
}
```

`clipboard clear` empties the Tk clipboard, and `clipboard append` copies new text to it. On Windows you can then paste this text using the normal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

`selection get` copies text from the current selection and throws an error if no text is selected. Use

```
    catch {clipboard append [selection get]}
```

to suppress such errors.

`selection clear` unselects the selection.

Comment: `<<Copy>>` is preferred to `<Control-c>`; makes the code more portable.